# Postgresql recursively parsing nested JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to parse a nested JSON in Postgres, which has the following structure:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "children": [{
            "id": 965,
            "children": [{
                    "id": 967
                },
                {
                    "id": 969
                },
                {
                    "id": 971
                },
                {
                    "id": 973
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 974,
            "children": [{
                    "id": 976
                },
                {
                    "id": 978
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My desired output form is this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|parent_id          |child_id             |
-------------------------------------------
|0                  |965                  |
|0                  |974                  |
|965                |967                  |
|965                |969                  |
|965                |971                  |
|965                |973                  |
|974                |976                  |
|974                |978                  |
-------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to use RECURSIVE CTEs to do so, however, with whatever I've tried, I run into either `could not identify an equality operator for type json` or `ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE`. I'm able to get the data for one level, but that's far from what I intend to do, so any suggestions as to what I could do differently would be of great help.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/a816653fae656038ab7ac07dafb76e88) is a how you can quickly try it out if needed, along with all what've I've tried and the errors those raised. Also it'd be a bonus if your suggestions work for `json` and `jsonb` both.

Thanks

Edit: The number of levels of the JSON isn't fixed, it could be upto any level (max 3-4).
Edit: Adding queries I tried here itself:

```
with recursive cte(id,json_element) as (
select tree->'id',tree->'children' from json_test
union
select json_element->'id',json_element->'children' from cte
) select * from cte;
--could not identify an equality operator for type json

WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, children) AS (
  SELECT
    tree->'id' as id,
    tree->'children' as children
  FROM json_test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    children -> 'id',
    children -> 'children'
  FROM cte,
    --json_each(CASE WHEN json_typeof(cte.children) <> 'object' THEN '{}' :: JSON ELSE cte.children END) AS t
    json_each(CASE WHEN json_typeof(cte.children) = 'array' THEN json_array_elements(cte.children) ELSE cte.children END) AS t
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE json_typeof(cte.children) <> 'object';
 --ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
  --Hint: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

I also tried multiple changes to these queries but ended up with the same errors in the end.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the queries, I wanted to keep the question more legible hence I had linked them in a gist.

Comment: A simple fix for "could not find equality operator" error return the values as text using `->>` instead of `->`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, that gives me: `ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown`

Comment: if `tree->'id'` works then `tree->>'id'` will work as well.

Comment: Yes, both `tree->'id'` and `tree->>'id'` work, giving the same result, but not in the desired form. Whereas, if I also add `tree->>'children'` and `json_element -> 'children'` , I get the the `ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=687a127fcf792d1232651c92194269e6)

```
WITH RECURSIVE jsondata AS (
    SELECT 
        data ->> 'id' as parent_id,
        data -> 'children' as children 
    FROM (
        SELECT '{"id": 0, "children": [{"id": 965, "children": [{"id": 967}, {"id": 969}, {"id": 971}, {"id": 973}]}, {"id": 974, "children": [{"id": 976}, {"id": 978}]}]}'::jsonb as data
    ) s

    UNION

    SELECT
        value ->> 'id',
        value -> 'children'
    FROM jsondata, jsonb_array_elements(jsondata.children)

)
SELECT 
    parent_id, 
    jsonb_array_elements(children) ->> 'id' 
FROM jsondata 
WHERE children IS NOT NULL
```

This is straight forward: Get the id of the current element as `parent_id`. Give the `children` array as new json object.

In the recursion part you have to expand the `children` array into one row per child. Not you can get the `id` and `children` as well.

Because this is done until the last child node (which has no own children per definition) their `children` columns are `NULL`. So these rows can be filtered out. The last step is to expand the `children` json objects and read their `id` elements to list them in the way you expect.

The columns are now of type `text`. Of course you could to an integer cast after all:

```
parent_id::int, 
(jsonb_array_elements(children) ->> 'id')::int
```

Comment: Thanks. I was repeatedly trying jsonb_array_elements(value -> 'children') in the `SELECT` part, and didn't think of putting it in the `FROM`.

Comment: BTW, can you tell me why you didn't use any arguments for your recursive CTE `jsondata` ?

Comment: If you do no define any arguments all columns of your initial SELECT are taken as arguments.